# symfony on windows with ruby and compass - error with paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, symfony, compass-sass

I'm using Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit with XAMPP 1.8.3.
Then I installed the RubyInstaller 1.9.3-p545.

After that I used `gem install sass` and `gem install compass`.

Now i have a problem with my paths.

config.yml snip:

```
assetic:
    ruby: C:\\tools\\Ruby193\\bin\\ruby
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        compass:
            bin: C:\\tools\\Ruby193\\bin\\compass
            apply_to: "\.scss$"
```

And the problem is that the `php app/console assetic:dump` command uses this paths.

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                                                                                                                  
An error occurred while running:                                                                                                                                                                     
"/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/ruby" "/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/compass" "compile" "C:\Users\PatrickB\AppData\Local\Temp" "--config" "C:\Users\PatrickB\AppData\Local\Temp\ass723D.tmp" "--sass-dir" "" "--css-dir" "" "C  
:/Users/PatrickB/AppData/Local/Temp/ass723E.tmp.scss"                                                                                                                                                     

Error Output:                                                                                                                                                                                        
    (GER) Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
    (ENG) The system cant find the specified path.
```

Comment: You need to work out which of those paths don't exist.

Comment: Thats a windows machine. No path exists. "/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/ruby" cant exists. "/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/compass" cant exists. On windows machines you havent a / directory like in ubuntu.